# Is the interior of the closure of $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My problem is proving whether this is true or not

> Is the interior of the closure of $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $int(cl(\mathbb{Q}))=\mathbb{R}$).

As $cl(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$, we can simplify the problem to whether $int(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. But I am unable to prove the last statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb R$ is open, it is equal to its interior.